# How to turn off invalid keypress beep in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Its very loud and unpleasant and I just know the settings for the terminal bell. But the terminal bell is useful and way more pleasant tune.

Comment: Lots of ways - https://serverfault.com/questions/26405/how-do-i-turn-off-the-beep-in-the-terminal-in-linux.

Comment: One of the A'ers to the dupe shows how to disable the Alert sound in GNOME3.